# Reference to compiler design

Tags: c, compiler-construction

What is the best book take it as a reference in compiler design
I have some knowledge in Compiler and I designed my own one once. but I need a reference because I'm going to be the teacher of a compiler course (practical, project) in C language.

Comment: read this for lab [lex & yacc, 2nd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do) Also read this page [Are there any compiler lectures available via video?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424796/are-there-any-compiler-lectures-available-via-video)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Sadly the question's been removed. That's a shame because there could have been some useful answers and resources there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compilers Principles,Techniques and Tools By A.V Aho,Ravi Sethi and J.D.Ullman - Pearson Education. First Refer old edition then jump on to new one

This is best and must read book for Compilers

Answer (score 2):

Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools best as far as i know